# C++ what is proper way to include STL container in my class?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

To begin with, I'm new to C++/OOP.

I want to include a std::map in my class and am wondering about how to provide users of my class the map typedefs and capabilities. Do I need to do as in the simple example below? (I've only shown a subset to indicate what I'm trying to do)

It doesn't feel right that I have to do this for any class where I've included a container (even for a subset of map methods). 
It also seems like a class maintenance issue (e.g. might not need some map method today, but it becomes needed in the future)

p.s. aside from replying to this question, any other corrections/feedback to the example below are appreciated.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Inventory {

public:
  typedef std::string key_type;
  typedef std::string mapped_type;
  typedef std::map<key_type, mapped_type>::value_type value_type;

  Inventory() { }
  Inventory(int lotNum) : lotNum_(lotNum) { }

  void insert(const value_type& el) { cars_.insert(el); } 

  //    
  // TODO: iterators, erase, etc
  //

private:
  int                             lotNum_;
  std::map<key_type, mapped_type> cars_;

};

int main() {

  Inventory ourCars(1);

  ourCars.insert( Inventory::value_type( "BMW","ABC123" ) );

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why even expose the internals to the caller?  If you need two strings then why not just have a function that takes two strings and you insert them into the map in the function.

Comment: Clients of your class can just use a `map` instead of your partially forwarding class. I suggest you think about `Inventory`s behavior instead, and implement *that*.

Comment: this question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would think about this problem. Think of your class interface and implementation separately. The user shouldn't need to know what you're doing behind the scenes - what containers you're using etc. Your class itself should have some functionality that you provide through its interface. I'm not sure what your class is supposed to do, but if you want a function to insert two strings you should just provide that function. That's your starting point. Then you decide that you're going to store your strings in a map or whatever. In summary, the types that go into the map will be decided by your class interface. What you're doing is the opposite - deciding how you're implementing it and then exposing the types of your map in the interface.